# How to multiply a list of numbers by 2 using a function? (Python)

Tags: python

I am a beginner and wanted to ask how to make a function that will multiply a list by 2 using a for loop. I am trying to find answers elsewhere but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: You should learn about list comprehension.

Comment: looks like everyone is just providing you a for loop solution. Are you trying to understand how to create a function or just the logic that multiplies the values in a list by 2 and prints it out? What are you looking for?

Comment: Joe ferndz, I am sorry for not seeing the comment, but I was looking for a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using a for loop you can do it like this:

```
the_list = [1,2,3,4]

for index in range(len(the_list)):
    the_list[index] = the_list[index]*2
```

But even more elegant is to use list comprehension and **using a function as you wanted**:

```
def multiply_array(the_list):
     new_list = [item*2 for item in the_list]
     return new_list
```

Comment: while these are great answers, I think he is asking how to create a function.

Comment: I  now changed it to a function instead of just an expression.

Comment: Same issue as with tk's answer - it rather suggests that the list comprehension is just an alternative implementation to the for loop, when one creates a new list and the other does an in-place modification.

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way is using list comprehension:

```py
def double(lst):
   return [x*2 for x in lst]
```

Equivalent is the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function - it maps an anonymous lambda function onto every element of a list:

```py
def double(lst):
   return list(map(lambda x: x*2, lst))
```

But you can do it in a for loop like this:

```py
def double(lst):
   for i in range(len(lst)):
      lst[i] *= 2
   return lst
```

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of the question - create a new list or do an in-place modification. I don't think the question is clear as to which, but choose one and state which you have chosen. Your options are presented as equivalent but do different things here. And where you do do an in-place modification, it is better to return `None` (compare `list.sort`), because modifying the list and also returning it can lead to confusion about what it does.

Comment: @alaniwi you make a good point. I have corrected it now to create a new list. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_new_list = [num * 2 for num in my_list]

>>> print(my_new_list)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution by using `for loop`

```
def multi():
    o=[]
    for i in a:
        b=i*2
        o.append(b)
    print(o)

a=[1,2,3,4]
multi()
```

Comment: he is asking for a function not just a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a function.  You would use the `def` statement to define the function.  Inside the function you would loop over indices using `range`, and you would use `*=` to multiply the existing value at each index by the specified number.

```
def double_it(your_list):
    for index in range(len(your_list)):
        your_list[index] *= 2
```

This will update the elements in the list. If there are other references to the list, then these will also see the new values. So for example, if you have:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
double_it(a)
print(b)
```

Then you will see the updated values in `b` also because it points to the same list.